# Exoplayer android stream audio

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have the next problem, in DataSourceFactory, when I create new DefaultDataSourceFactory, I have the next error 'Wrong 1st argument type Found 'android.View.OnClicklistener' required 'android...Context' in Util.getUserAgent(this...)

```
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
            final ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
            TrackSelection.Factory trackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
            DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this,
                    getPackageName()), bandwidthMeter);
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(cuento.getUrl()),
                    dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, new Handler(), Throwable::printStackTrace);
        }
    });
```

Why? I tried with getApplicationContext(), or Myclass.this, or private Context mContext, but nothing solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are inside a inner class **this** passes a reference to the inner class, so you need to call `getContext()` or `YourAcitivty.this`

but from what you explained the error is about Util.getUserAgent, so replace you code with the following.

```
          DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getContext(), Util.getUserAgent(getContext(),
                getPackageName()), bandwidthMeter);
```